# get array from mongodb java

Tags: java, mongodb

Faced with a problem: I need to take a list from the database, add an item there and write the updated list back. But the problem is the following error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to class java.util.List (java.lang.Boolean and java.util.List are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`.

My code:

```
Document doc = collection.find(new Document("_id", event.getGuild().getId())).first();
List<Document> links = (List<Document>) doc.get("links");
links.add(new Document(e.getMessage().getContentDisplay().trim(), "enable"));
collection.updateOne(
   new Document("_id", event.getGuild().getId()),
   new Document("$set", new Document("links", links))
);
```

What do I need to do to avoid making a mistake?
My Document Structure:

```
{
   "_id": "guild id", 
   "links": [{"link1": "enable"}, {"link2": "enable"}]
}
```

Full error log:

```
[JDA [0 / 2] MainWS-ReadThread] ERROR JDA - One of the EventListeners had an uncaught exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to class java.util.List (java.lang.Boolean and java.util.List are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at listeners.ButtonClick.lambda$onButtonInteraction$3(ButtonClick.java:59)
        at com.jagrosh.jdautilities.commons.waiter.EventWaiter$WaitingEvent.attempt(EventWaiter.java:293)
        at com.jagrosh.jdautilities.commons.waiter.EventWaiter.lambda$onEvent$2(EventWaiter.java:250)
        at java.base/java.util.Collection.removeIf(Collection.java:576)
        at com.jagrosh.jdautilities.commons.waiter.EventWaiter.onEvent(EventWaiter.java:250)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.InterfacedEventManager.handle(InterfacedEventManager.java:96)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handleInternally(EventManagerProxy.java:88)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handle(EventManagerProxy.java:70)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.JDAImpl.handleEvent(JDAImpl.java:164)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.MessageCreateHandler.handleInternally(MessageCreateHandler.java:121)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:36)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onDispatch(WebSocketClient.java:952)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onEvent(WebSocketClient.java:839)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.handleEvent(WebSocketClient.java:817)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onBinaryMessage(WebSocketClient.java:991)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnBinaryMessage(ListenerManager.java:385)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnBinaryMessage(ReadingThread.java:276)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleBinaryFrame(ReadingThread.java:996)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:755)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:108)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.runMain(ReadingThread.java:64)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketThread.run(WebSocketThread.java:45)
```

P.S. I use JDA & mongodb-driver-sync libs

Answer (score 0):

**What do I need to do to avoid making a mistake?**

The problem is here

```
List<Document> links = (List<Document>) doc.get("links");
```

As the error says, you are trying to cast the return type Boolean to List, wich will generate a class cast exception.

Comment: I don't quite understand where the boolean type comes from.  I don't use it anywhere

Comment: Even if I change the get method to getList the error doesn't change

Comment: Can you provide the full log of the error ?

Comment: Yes, I changed my question